# Chat meta gives me A certificate warning

Tags: bug, meta, chat

The link : https://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Gives me a security warning :

> There is a problem with this website's security certificate

The certificate is not expired (700+ days left).
And looks valid for me.

Comment: There isn't a chat.meta.stackoverflow.com - it's a redirect to chat.meta.stackexchange.com - use chat.stackoverflow.com if you want SO chat...

Comment: The HTTP version responds with a 301 Redirect to `https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com` but the HTTPS version responds with a 200 OK.

Comment: @JonClements, "There isn't a chat.meta.stackoverflow.com" the jedi mind trick worked on me but the droid didn't modify his link.

Comment: @DragandDrop but that's not the droid or link you're looking for... *waves paw*